# iOS 11 issue - bar button action does not fire if gesture added to navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

This was working perfectly on iOS 10. But does not work on iOS 11. `showFlyoutMenu` not firing up.

```
gestureLeftArrow = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftArrowGesture:)];
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:gestureLeftArrow];

            gestureRightArrow = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightArrowGesture:)];
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:gestureRightArrow];  


UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"hamburger-new.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        UIBarButtonItem *flyoutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showFlyoutMenu)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flyoutButton;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `cancelsTouchesInView` of your gesture recognizers to `false`.
See: [cancelsTouchesInView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624218-cancelstouchesinview)

> **Discussion**
>   When this property is true (the default) and the receiver recognizes its gesture, the touches of that gesture that are pending are not delivered to the view and previously delivered touches are cancelled through a touchesCancelled(_:with:) message sent to the view. If a gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if the value of this property is false, the view receives all touches in the multi-touch sequence.

Comment: Yup. Just found the solution. And want to add, this is already fixed in iOS 11.2